# MongoDB NoSQL Injection - Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sql-injection, nosql-injection

I'm using MongoDB 4.2 with Express > 4.

I'm trying to execute a NoSQL Injection using node.js. This is the *.ejs* code of a form with username and password:

```
 <body>
    <form action="/login_db/login_db" method="POST" >
      <input placeholder="name" name="name"> </br>
      <input placeholder="password" name="password"> </br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
```

I have a local MongoDB Database with user that are allowed to get access through the db. This is the *.js* code:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const dbname = "mydb";

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const mongoOptions = {useNewUrlParser : true};

const state = {
    db : null
};

const connect = (cb) =>{

    if(state.db)
        cb();
    else{
        MongoClient.connect(url,mongoOptions,(err,client)=>{
            if(err)
                cb(err);
            else{
                state.db = client.db(dbname);
                cb();
            }
        });
    }
}

const getPrimaryKey = (_id)=>{
    return ObjectID(_id);
}

const getDB = ()=>{
    return state.db;
}

module.exports = {getDB,connect,getPrimaryKey};
```

And this is the *.js* login_db-route.js:

```
"use strict"
const router = require('express').Router();
const db = require("../db");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const express = require('express');

const collection = "amministrazione";


const app = express()
const path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')



router.get('/login_db', function(req,res){
 console.log('login request');
  var cursor = db.getDB().collection(collection).find().toArray(function(err, results) {
    res.render('login_db.ejs', {quotes: results, user: req.user});
  });

});


router.post('/login_db', function (req, res) {
   console.log('login post request');
  var name = req.body.name;
  var password = req.body.password;
   db.getDB().collection(collection).findOne({"name" : name, "password" : password},  (err, result) =>{
     if(result == null || result.length == 0){
       console.log('user not found '+ err);
       return res.render('login_db.ejs',{user: req.user});
     }
     console.log('User found' + result);
     db.getDB().collection(collection).find().toArray((err, result)=>{
       if(err) return console.log(err)
       res.render('book.ejs', {quotes:result,user: req.user, flag: true});
     })
   })
});


module.exports = router;
```

The code that i wrote is vulnerable to nosql injection, but when i try to insert into the form a MongoDB Payload, such as:

```
{ $gt : "a" }
{ $gt : "a" }
```

i can't have login success. Where is the problem? Is there a way not to consider the **"** ?

Thanks to anyone who helped me.

Comment: do you mean username = "{ $gt : "a" }" to check nosql injection?

Comment: if you log your payload by console.log, you can see that `"` is changed to `\"`.

Comment: Yes, mongodb receive "{ $gt : "a"}" instead of { $gt: "a"}  due to the JavaScript interpretation of parameters as primitive strings

Comment: I tried to do console.log of payload but the " remain "

Comment: Do you want to add `"` to mongodb? Otherwise, do you want to check `"` on node.js side?

Comment: I wanna pass to mongodb only {$gt : "a"} because now mongodb receive "{$gt : "a"}" which is interpreted as a string and not evaluated (so I don't achieve the nosql injection)

Comment: now, I got your question. Can you please add code to pass {$gt : "a"} to mongodb? Then, I'll post updated code with solution.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html - and the solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize

Comment: Try URL like `...?name["$ne"]=1&password["$ne"]=1` This may let to successful injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your code.

```
var name = req.body.name;
var password = req.body.password;
db.getDB().collection(collection).findOne({"name" : name, "password" : password});
```

If you pass those parameters, the mongodb query will be like this.

```
db.getDB().collection(collection).findOne({"name" : "{ $gt : \"a\" }", "password" : "{ $gt : \"a\" }"});
```

If you want to pass those parameters as query but not string, you can add some code like this.

```
var name = req.body.name;
var password = req.body.password;

try {
    name = JSON.parse(name);
} catch (e){}
try {
    password = JSON.parse(password);
} catch (e){}

db.getDB().collection(collection).findOne({"name" : name, "password" : password });
```